# Forward Windows logs to Linux server

Tags: syslog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software to send windows notification eventlogs to linux syslog server and encode to utf8](https://serverfault.com/questions/232240/software-to-send-windows-notification-eventlogs-to-linux-syslog-server-and-encode)

Is it possible to forward logs from a Windows server to a Linux syslog server ?

Comment: Did you even try to conduct some kind of research on your own? Searching for "eventlog syslog" on google brings tons of results..

Comment: @pauska The argument one could make is that ServerFault strives to be the first and best Google result for all server related questions. Even the obvious, easy and lazy questions belong here.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Just store them?

Comment: its my general impression that there's very little overall consensus of what belongs on each stack exchange site.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/232240/software-to-send-windows-notification-eventlogs-to-linux-syslog-server-and-encode

Comment: From the looks of ladadadada's comment, this should probably be closed as a "duplicate" (already answered)

Comment: @kennyrasschaert: looks like a search of the site would have turned up an answer for sending event log data to Linux :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://www.kiwisyslog.com/kiwi-syslog-server-overview/ for this.